# WinDBG - Mismatching JavaScript and dx behaviour

Tags: windbg

I am writing a simple JavaScript WinDBG script, however, I can't properly map the operands used in an instruction mapped by `host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Code.CreateDissassembler().DisassembleBlocks(addr)[addr].Instructions[addr]`

I can list the operands with a `for(var o of instruction.Operands)` loop, but that doesn't particularly make sense considering that the order of operands is essential.
So I have to convert that manually to an array, hoping that the order is preserved…?

What is even more confusing is that if I evaluate the same expression with `dx`, it behaves as an array. Namely, `dx Debugger.Utility.Code.CreateDisassembler().DisassembleBlocks(0x7900ffff)[0x7900ffff].Instructions[0x7900ffff].Operands[0]` does return the first operand, and `(…).Operands[1]` returns the second operand; while in JavaScript this same exact command will return `undefined`.

All I was able to find from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dbgmodel-object-instruction) is that `Operands` returns "A collection of operand objects describing the operands of the instruction."

Is this the expected behaviour, or am I missing something?

Edit: As pointed out, a minimal reproducible example:

```js
// Retrieves operand for current instruction pointed by EIP
function run() {
    var p = host.currentThread.Registers.User.eip;
    var instr = host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Code.CreateDisassembler().DisassembleBlocks(p)[p].Instructions[p];
    host.diagnostics.debugLog(`Operand: ${instr.Operands[0]}\n`); // "Operand: undefined"
    // Incompatible with: `dx Debugger.Utility.Code.CreateDisassembler().DisassembleBlocks(@eip)[@eip].Instructions[@eip].Operands[0]` --> Attributes | ImmediateValue: (…) | Registers
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a [mre] for everyone to reproduce? Even if nobody can help here, it's probably good to have it when filing a bug at Microsoft.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I didn't initially add it as it depends on a single call pretty much, but it does sound like good practice, so added an example script! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Did a test script and also confirmed on my side (windbg preview 1.2210.3001). There's definitely something amiss with the instruction object you receive. I guess it's not converted to a native JS array, hence not subscriptable. On the other hand you can apply LINQ functions to it, so `.First()`, `.Last()` and the other LINQ functions work on it... As a side note, Windbg preview from the store is not "preview" anymore ([since a few days ago](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/)), it might have been fixed in latest release (which need to be installed separately).

Comment: @Neitsa I was asking myself last week when we would get a non-Preview version, and I completely missed it was just out! It does persist in the new version, but as mentioned in William's answer it seems it is "by design", even if not ideal and possibly to be changed in future releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Operands* object on an instruction is, unfortunately, just an iterable container.  It does not presently support indexing.  There is, however, a guarantee that a for...of will maintain the order of what's in the container **and** that the order of operands in the container is the order of operands within the instruction.

The evaluator for **dx** has a bit of "extra support" for [] on iterable containers in order to make the debugger hyperlinks function.  For any object which is iterable but not indexable, doing [n] within the **dx** evaluator will, in effect, start iterating the container, advance to the n-th element, and return that.  The scripting model does not do that for indexing operations.

That said -- operands is one of those things which should be indexable.  I can make sure that gets fixed...

Comment: Thank you! It's not too much of a hassle to use `.First()` and `.Last()`, it's what I ended up doing in the end. It was, most of all, the inconsistency between the two, and not having certainty regarding the order, having an answer on both is great. Even though it being indexable would be much more intuitive indeed. Thanks again for your answer, and the work on WinDBG!